# XNA 3.1 on dotnet framework 4.0 on XP embedded

Tags: .net, xna, windows-xp-embedded

Is it possible to install XNA framework 3.1 on a system which has only dotNet frame 4.0. We have a product which runs on XP embedded and previously we were using dotNet framework 3.5 and XNA 3.1. Now we wanted to update to DotNet framework 4.0 and after doing that I am not able to install XNA 3.1, but I can install XNA 4.0 version. But the problem is our games are created in XNA 3.1 and I am not able to run it. Also, our XP embedded image is restricted to 2GB in size so I can only have dot Net framework 4.0 or 3.5 cannot install both of them.

So, please let me know if it is possible to install XNA 3.1 on dotNet framework 4.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NOTE: This Q&A currently is *only* relevant to *XP embedded*. For anyone else coming here from a "mainstream" Windows OS, your .NET 4.0 *includes* older .Net frameworks, so this is a non-issue. If you need to *build* (in Visual Studio) targetting an older .NET framework, then make sure the desired framework is selected as the target in project properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some answer and it's not quite simple.

---

In general, my recommendation is to leave the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2, 3.5 SP1 and 4 installed on your computer.

Unlike previous versions of the .NET Framework, the .NET Framework 4 does not allow an application that was built with previous versions of the .NET Framework to migrate forward and run on it if the previous version is not installed. If you are using any applications that were built with any version of the .NET Framework before version 4, then I recommend leaving both the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and the .NET Framework 4 installed.

You cannot use the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 unless you also have the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 and 3.0 SP2 installed. Therefore, you will not be allowed to uninstall the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 or 3.0 SP2 if you have the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed. If you try to uninstall the .NET Framework 2.0 or 3.0 when the .NET Framework 3.5 is installed, their uninstall processes will block and tell you that they are needed by another application on your system.

The .NET Framework 1.0 and .NET Framework 1.1 can be installed side-by-side with the .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4. Most applications that were created for the .NET Framework 1.0 or 1.1 will automatically use the .NET Framework 2.0 instead if it is installed on the system. In most cases, that means you do not need to keep the .NET Framework 1.0 or 1.1 installed on your system if you already have the .NET Framework 2.0 installed.

However, there are some applications that are configured to require a specific version of the .NET Framework, even if later versions of the .NET Framework are installed. If you have any applications like that on your system and try to run them without installing the .NET Framework 1.0 or 1.1, you will get an error message that looks like the following:

```
--------------------------- 
MyApplication.exe - .NET Framework Initialization Error 
--------------------------- 
To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework: 
v1.1.4322 
Contact your application publisher for instructions about obtaining the appropriate version of the .NET Framework. 
--------------------------- 
OK 
---------------------------
```

In the above error message, the version number will be v1.0.3705 if you need to install the .NET Framework 1.0, and it will be v1.1.4322 if you need to install the .NET Framework 1.1.

If you end up seeing any error messages like this, you can re-install the .NET Framework 1.0 or 1.1 in order to resolve the errors. If you don't end up seeing any error messages like this, then you don't need to worry about re-installing the .NET Framework 1.0 or 1.1.

Comment: Davor, for XNA 3.1 installation, I was getting an error to install atleast dotNet 2.0 version, but since I have disk space  restrictions I am not able to complete the installation.I hardly have 170MB free space on my HD. Yes, we cannot run legacy application in dot Net 4.0, so to handle that issue I resolved it by creating a App.Config and provided the SupportedRunTime versions and they are working fine. But I cannot do the same for XNA 3.1 installation

Comment: I realy cant help you more... this text i found when i was looking for similar situation. maybe converting game from 3.1 to 4? quite a big task.

Comment: No Worries Davor, I think that is the only option left, thanks for your comments though...